# Is there way to stop helm upgrade or create immutable config map in helm with kubernates v1.13 version?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Is there any good approach to make immutable config map in kubernates v1.13.

Below one will work in alpha version v1.18 but not working with v1.13 GA version.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  ...
data:
  ...
immutable: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Immutable ConfigMaps are [new in Kubernetes 1.18](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/#mounted-configmaps-are-updated-automatically) (and are alpha and behind a feature gate), so older versions of Kubernetes won't understand this YAML.

In your Helm logic you can make the `immutable:` line dependent on the Kubernetes version:

```
{{- if semverCompare ">= 1.18" .Capabilities.KubeVersion.Version }}
immutable: true
{{- end }}
```

You may also want to include a specific `.Values` check here, since Helm doesn't have a way to check the feature-gate capability.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,but

In v1.15 is there any way can i stop updating the helm ?
So that configmap cannot be altered?

Comment: David Maze can you help on the kubernates 1.15 version

Comment: If you are not on k8s 1.18 or if this alpha feature is not enabled, you cannot prevent a ConfigMap's content from changing.

Comment: David Maze -Can we use the pre-upgrade hook and try to stop the helm upgrade?
Like on pre-upgrade hook run one shell script file and exit the process if you are trying to do helm upgrade to change the configmap content in k8s-1.15